# Does Thermal Paste Function Deteriorate Over Time?

Tags: imac, thermal-paste

I received a iMac thats from 2011 and I am planning to refurbish it. It seems to work with an exception of that it shuts down due to overheating (too much dust and other stuff inside). I have completely overhauled it. Now my main question is: Is it advisable to open the cpu and gpu and clean the thermal paste and re-apply? Do thermal paste deteriorate in its effect over time? I am reluctant to open the cpu and gpu because the factory thermal paste is very specialized for iMacs and applied in more controlled way then normal pc building practices.

Comment: "_... the factory thermal paste is very specialized for iMacs and applied in more controlled way then normal pc building practices_" ... it is? I suppose they may hold themselves to a higher standard than other manufacturers, but I wouldn't think it's particularly special.

Comment: Apple's original thermal compound is legendarily bad. It's not uncommon to hear that changing their paste in a _new_ Mac to something better improves temperatures by 3-10°C.

Comment: @Attie well what I meant by applied in more controlled way, I pertained to automated tooling so the spread is optimal. I just read that the gap for gpu vram and cooling plate is larger so a depth needs to be there in the thermal pad to have proper contacts with vram.

Comment: @gronostaj i didnt know that. I was actually planning on purchasing the same thermal paste that is used in iMac's if re-pasting is recommended. Are you suggesting ordinary thermal paste might suffice?

Comment: The original Apple stuff is almost impossible to get. It's not available as a consumer product. Just buy some good quality thermal paste and you should be fine. For example Arctic MX-4 has good price/performance ratio. Don't worry about perfect application - just make sure to apply enough. Pressure of the cooler will distribute it evenly. Overflow of excess thermal paste has been shown experimentally to barely affect performance and as long as you avoid liquid metal solutions, it won't damage the hardware.

Comment: @gronostaj perfect! thats all I needed to hear. Virtuality in below answer did recommend same brand Arctic Silver 5.

Comment: @gfdsal "_gpu vram and cooling plate is larger so a depth needs to be there in the thermal pad to have proper contacts with vram_" - note if the parts are not in direct contact, as it sounds like here, then you should keep and reuse the pad(s) or get new ones of the appropriate height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermal paste **does** deteriorate and become old over time, yes. Most thermal paste lasts about 4 years before it starts to lose effectiveness.

It is advised that you replace the thermal paste if you can; this will allow the CPU and GPU to function to the best of its ability as it reduces thermal throttling due to inadequate heat dissipation, which can be caused by old thermal paste or a clogged up fan. If you want to refurbish the iMac and get it running as well as possible, then it's recommended to replace the thermal paste if you can.

You mentioned that it shuts down due to overheating, and replacing the thermal paste would be one more obvious step to take to help the computer's thermal performance, so it is recommended to replace the thermal paste due to this fact as well.

Also, I don't believe that iMacs need any sort of 'special' thermal paste, any will work. Any thermal paste works effectively on iMacs, Macbooks, etc, as far as I know.

In addition, I recommend 99% pure Isopropyl Alcohol (IPA) and a Q-Tip/cotton bud to get the surface of the CPU/GPU squeaky clean before you apply new thermal paste.

I hope this is able to help you in some way.

Comment: I see makes sense. Their use different thermal paste for cpu and different for gpu so there might be some science involved apart from economy. I am just worried about the vram for the gpu as it has slightly larger gaps due to its short height against the cooling plate. Any paste that you recomment that you have used in iMacs or Macbooks and seemed to work well?

Comment: I'd probably recommend Arctic Silver 5.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it advisable to open the cpu and gpu and clean the thermal paste and re-apply?

I don't have intimate knowledge of the Apple cooling solutions, and it depends on the compound they're actually using as to wheter it "*goes bad*" over time, and what sort of timeframe that may be... but pastes can often dry up, crack and become less effective.

High temperatures can speed up the deterioation of any thermal interface that is present.

I'd suggest that if you're struggling with thermal issues, then it would be a very good idea to properly clean down the parts and apply new a thermal interface. Use IPA or a similar solvent to achieve a nice clean surface, and remember that even the oils from fingerprints can act against you in this regard.

Do you have anyone you can ask for support if you're not confident doing this?

Comment: Yes, i cleaned everything even the fans with IPA because the iMac was heating up. As far as thermal paste is concerned I shall replace it. Also for the last question: I have good community people like yourself that I can ask for support in such forums :)

Comment: @gfdsal great! nothing wrong with asking for help!